# How to write number under fraction

Tags: fractions

Is it possible to write a number under a fraction like below image?

I found `underbrace` but I don't need a brace among fraction and number.

[image: Fraction example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\underbracket[0pt]{\frac{5}{9}}_{(7)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\underset` (or `\overset`) might come in handy for this (`\strut`s provide some additional spacing):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  f(x) = \underset{\strut(7)}{\frac{5}{9}} + \overset{\strut(8)}{\frac{4}{9}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works too.

Comment: Thanks a lot Werner. As Jpi said, this is also very helpful.